# Pregunta sobre Arreglos en Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hola tengo que realizar un ejercicio en Javascript que me diga en que posición esta el valor del arreglo y sumarle 5
Ejemplo: El elemento 0 del arreglo es (X) y su valor final es (X+5).

Hasta ahora la posición no es problema, solo no se como agregarle la suma individual de los valores.

```js
var miArreglo = [101,102,103,104,105,106]
var a=5;


console.info("La primera posición es " + miArreglo[0],"Y su valor final es")
```

Comment: podrias usar indexOf, busca el dato en el arreglo y retornaria en que posicion se encontro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No entendí si debes buscar la posición o ya está establecida... basandome en tu ejemplo, donde ya esta establecida, esto te tendría que funcionar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    let miArreglo = [101,102,103,104,105,106];
    console.log(miArreglo[0]);
    let posicion = miArreglo[0];
    let valorfinal = posicion + 5;
    console.log("valor final es: "+valorfinal);
</script>
```

Comment: De hecho este código funciona perfecto, solo cambiare el log por alert y me funcionara, les agradezco mucho.

Answer (score 1):

Primero pides el dato a buscar en el arreglo con un prompt y ese dato es el que buscas on el metodo `indexOf` pero como es para string primero se convierte a string para buscarlo y al ultimo se vuelve a parsear a int para sumarle los 5, seria algo como:

```js
var miArreglo = [101,102,103,104,105,106]
var a=5;
var numeroABuscar = prompt("Introduzca el dato");
 
for (busqueda in miArreglo) {
 if (miArreglo[busqueda].toString().indexOf(numeroABuscar) != -1) {
  document.write("El dato esta en la posicion:  " + busqueda + "y su valor final es:  " +(miArreglo[busqueda]+ 5))
  break;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si es lo que quieres pero lo pongo

```
let miArreglo = [101,102,103,104,105,106]
let aSumar = 5
let aBuscar = 103;

let posicion = null;
for (var i = 0; i < miArreglo.length; i++) {
    if (miArreglo[i] == aBuscar) {
        posicion = i;
    }
}

if (posicion != null) {
    console.info(`El valor ${aBuscar} esta en la posición ${posicion} y el valor final es ${miArreglo[posicion] + aSumar}`)
}else{
    console.info("No se encontro")
}
```

o tal vez quieres esto

```
let miArreglo = [101,102,103,104,105,106]
let aSumar = 5

for (var i = 0; i < miArreglo.length; i++) {
    console.info(`El valor ${miArreglo[i]} esta en la posición ${i} y el valor final es ${miArreglo[i] + aSumar}`)
}
```